# count next to several columns

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, conventions

So i'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way of querying a db where:
I am joining several tables,
am selecting around 5 or so columns from each table,
and from one of these tables, I am simply counting the number of corrective actions associated with each discrepancy.

So something like:

```
select D.discrepancyID, MAX(D.discrepancyComment), MAX(A.make), MAX(A.model),  Count(CA.CorrectiveActionID)
from Discrepancy D
left join Automobile A on A.autoID = D.autoID
left join CorrectiveActions CA on CA.discrepancyID = D.discrepancyID
group by D.discrepancyID
```

I'm just thinking that there must be a better way of getting the corrective action count within this query without having to get the max out of every other column, am I right?

Comment: Are `d.discrepancyid` and `a.autoid` primary keys of those tables? If so it doesn't look like the `max` aggregates are achieving anything, and you could add those columns to the `group by` instead. Or does that give different results, and if so why?

Comment: They aren't doing anything other than allowing the query to run, they will go into the group by as Gordon Linoff recommended, as at the very least it looks cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put these in the `group by` clause:

```
select D.discrepancyID, D.discrepancyComment, A.make, A.model, Count(CA.CorrectiveActionID)
from Discrepancy D left join
     Automobile A
     on A.autoID = D.autoID left join
     CorrectiveActions CA
     on CA.discrepancyID = D.discrepancyID
group by D.discrepancyID, D.discrepancyComment, A.make, A.model;
```

However, this probably won't have much impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the counts within an inline view. The downside to performance would be that you are scanning the `Discrepancy` table two times.

```
select D.discrepancyID, D.discrepancyComment, A.make, A.model, CorrectiveActionCounts.Count_CorrectiveAction
from Discrepancy D
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
D.discrepancyID AS discrepancyID, 
Count(CA.CorrectiveActionID) AS Count_CorrectiveAction
from Discrepancy D
LEFT JOIN CorrectiveActions CA on CA.discrepancyID = D.discrepancyID
GROUP BY D.discrepancyID
) CorrectiveActionCounts
ON CorrectiveActionCounts.discrepancyID = D.discrepancyID
LEFT JOIN Automobile A on A.autoID = D.autoID;
```